# Inserting form values into Excel spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert form values into my Excel spreadsheet using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) but my current code is inserting values into the same row.

1. As my table starts from **row 3**, I want to start from there and continue by automatically shifting to the next row each time. The rows are already set and I don't want to insert new rows but overwrite the current 'empty' rows.
2. When 202 rows (maximum no. of rows available) have been entered then I want the spreadsheet to return an error message dialog.

How can I go about achieving this?

**Current Code**

```
    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("main")

    ' Copy the data to the database
    ws.Rows("4:4").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ws.Range("A3").Value = cbo_deptCode.Value
    MsgBox ("Booking request has been successfully made")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("main")
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)
    If rng1.Row > 202 Then
    MsgBox "202 Rows exceeded"  
    Else
    rng1.Offset(1, 0) = cbo_deptCode.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and let us know if you have any questions or concerns:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("main")

    ' Copy the data to the database
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Get last empty cell in column A
    If i > 202 Then
        MsgBox "Row 203"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Range("A" & i).Value = cbo_deptCode.Value
    MsgBox ("Booking request has been successfully made")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it works really well. But I'm having the problem where it always skips row 3 for some reason. Even though it is the current first empty row on the table, it skips it and starts at row 4. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @methuselah The code above doesn't actually use `ws`. It works on the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Sry, I was away... But I see you got your answer :)